# python program to find maximal in 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write program that print maximal points of the input but it is not giving correct output.

Definition of maximal-
Given a set of points `P = {p1,p2,...,pn}` in 2-space, each represented by its `x` and `y` integer coordinates, output the set of the maximal points of `P`, that is, those points `pi`, such that `pi` is not dominated by any other point of `P` (not both coordinate are dominated)

Example input:

```
p1(5,7),p2(47,84),p3(89,4),(46,54),(100,1)
```

Example outut:

```
p2(47,84),(89,4),(100,1)
```

The idea of my program is to first sort the point according to `x` axis then compare the `y` coordinate.

```
a=[[5,7],[47,84],[89,4][46,54],[100,1]]

#sort according to x axis
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

#compare y coordinate of i to all element right to i
for i in reversed(range(len(a)):
   j=i+1
   while (j<len(a)): 
        if(mylist[i][1]>mylist[j][1]):
             j+=1
   if(j==len(a)):
          print(mylist[i])
```

Comment: Your definition of maximal is completely unclear to me. What do you mean by "dominated" and "not both coordinate are dominated"?

Comment: why do you set up 'a' like this? you generate an array of arrays instead of passing just the vector-tuple as you have in the example input. So it would be like this a =[(5,7),(47,84)] and so on or even better just pass it the points a=[p1,p2,p3] and acess them via a[index_of_a][index_of_p]. egg a[0][0] ... to find out more read about tuples.

Comment: come on, definition combined with examples is pretty clear

Comment: @TheFool Initially I am trying to solve with simple 2d array not using set of points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's really not how you'd do that in Python. Use language elements that help you express what's going on, that way the code gets more understandable and, as a bonus, more concise. You want to find all elements of `a` for which no other element of `a` is greater in both coordinates:

```
a=[[5,7],[47,84],[89,4],[46,54],[100,1]]
for point in a:
  if not any(map(lambda p: p[0] > point[0] and p[1] > point[1], a)):
    print(point)
```

You could also use a list comprehension instead of `map`, which might be a bit more efficient:

```
a=[[5,7],[47,84],[89,4],[46,54],[100,1]]
for point in a:
  if not any([p[0] > point[0] and p[1] > point[1] for p in a]):
    print(point)
```